# How to rename a movie file and also files ins subdirectories (e.g. subtitles) beginning with same prefix

Tags: shell-script, batch-rename

I've several directories with movie files ,
and also subdirectories with subtitles files with same prefix or starting with same prefix.

I want to rename subtitles files with the Directory name it is contained as shown in example.

**Example**:

```
Directory "My.favorite.Movie.1080p":
abc-myfav-1080p.mkv
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p.idx
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p.sub
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p-eng.idx
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p-eng.sub
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p-forced.idx
Subs\abc-myfav-1080p-forced.sub
```

they should be renamed to:

```
Directory "My.favorite.Movie.1080p":
My favorite Movie 1080p.mkv
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p.idx
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p.sub
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p-eng.idx
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p-eng.sub
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p-forced.idx
Subs\My favorite Movie 1080p-forced.sub
```

Does anybody can tell me a **Windows Batch Script** or a **bash script** (which i can apply by *Mobaxterm*)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to prefer cygwin for running bash scripts under windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php) allows you to set up conditions for renaming a list of files.  In this case, you can replace any instance of "abc-myfav-" with "My favorite Movie ".

[image: BRU]

You can also enable the subfolders checkbox to specify how far down you would like to rename.  Allowing you to rename from the root directory down to the "Subs" folder in one shot.

Comment: Thx n.t., but this tool didn't run recursive over x folders and pick the "Folder Name" automatically as to-replace Movie name!? Thx, Kuddel